# Magento 2: How to not use URL /home

Tags: magento2, cms, home-page, url-key

By default, Magento uses the URL key 'home' for the CMS homepage. The problem is that the homepage now has 2 URL's. http://example.com/home and  http://example.com/. I don't like this behaviour, it also may affect SEO.

Magento doesn't allow changing the URL key to '/' or ''. Is there a decent method to resolve this without having to resort to canonical tags or 301 redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, /home should NOT be crawl from sitemap.xml. Magento 2 is excluded from this page Url from the sitemap. xml.

In your case, I suggest simple **htaccess** redirection if you using **apache**.

> `RedirectMatch 301  /home /`

Comment: This will work, but you will still see the url '/home' popup whenever a module tries to get the url for the CMS homepage. Magento should probably extend the method for retrieving URL's to make an exception for the homepage so it only returns the root URL.